# Search to MySQL table using jQuery, Ajax and PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a search engine for a MySQL table with jQuery, Ajax and PHP. I have a database on my external server in order to get data from. Here is a pic of the MySQL database table. [image]
I have these two scripts for the search engine:

**index.html**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="searchdb"/>
        <div id="resultdb"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#searchdb').change(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'getdb.php',
                        data: 'ip=' + $('#searchdb').val(),
                        success: function(msg) {
                            $('#resultdb').html(msg);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**getdb.php**

```
<?php
if ($_GET['insert']) :
    $insert = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['insert']);
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "mydb";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM test WHERE id='.$insert.'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc() 
            echo $row["name"];
    }
endif;
?>
```

What I want is to type the id, hit enter and get back the name or "0 results". There seems to be something wrong with the code I wrote. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're creating a query string with `ip`, but your PHP code looks for `insert`. You're also missing a semi-colon after `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` in your PHP code. There may be other errors.

Comment: Might be stretching things a bit calling this a `search engine`??

Comment: [**How to debug small programs** http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @HoboSapiens thanks for the notice. This mistake was made when I edited the code for putting that question here. I'm really sorry for that. The problem was that I used .$insert. and not $insert.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm really sorry for calling that a search engine but because I'm learning to code right now this looks like a search engine to a beginer. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @spencer7593 Didn't know that and I'm really sorry for posting that question. Thanks you.

Comment: @VaggelisKarathanos no need to apologize and don't be offended

Answer (score 1):

The period characters in your SQL text string are being interpreted as literal dot characters, not PHP concatenation.

e.g.

```
     $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM test WHERE id='.$insert.'";
     echo "SQL=" . $sql;
```

should return:

```
     SQL=SELECT id, name FROM test WHERE id='.123.'
```

That would be easy enough to fix. But why include the value as part of the SQL text in the first place.

Using prepared statements and bind placeholders is really *not that hard*.

Use a static string as a SQL statement, use a question mark as a bind place holder, and call the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` function. And check the prepare and execute calls for errors. (Those return FALSE if an error occurs.) And the call to num_rows isn't necessary. Just do a fetch. If it returns a row, you've got a row. If it returns FALSE, there wasn't a row to return.

Something like this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM test WHERE id = ? ";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$insert);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            if ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row['name'];
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
        } else {
            // handle error
            die $conn->error;
        }
    } else {
         // handle error
         die $conn->error;
    }
```

You could handle the error conditions differently, depending on your requirements.

Comment: **NOTE**: The example syntax shown in my answer using `die` won't work without parens. (Excuse me my Perl is showing.) But you probably don't want to use `die`. You could just use `echo` if you want to return the error string to the caller.